# When Calling a Function Defined from useContext I am Receiving an Error Stating it is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a web app for the first time and a lot of it is still very new to me. I'm running into some problems with functions that I have imported via Context to child components.

**So the ideal workflow goes as follows:**

1. A user accesses the app and is asked to log in.
2. The user successfully logs in and the app retrieves their user
   profile via a series API calls.
3. During these API calls I also call upon two context functions I
   destructured for the component.

   One context function sets the state of a "loggedIn" value to true

   Another context function sets the state of a "userState" value to
   contain the userProfile object.

   These values are also set into local storage under the same name.
4. From here the states have been updated so the page should re-render
   and utilize the newly available information from the global state.
5. Subsequently, the user should be able to refresh the page and not
   need to re-login so at the start of the component I also call the
   context functions and pass in the value that was stored in local
   storage to keep them up to date.

**What is actually happening:**

To provide further context, my web app has multiple "tabs" in the header that when selected will render a different component inside the parent. This is where the problem is occurring. The above workflow seems to be working fine even when refreshing but when I click on a tab whose component tries to call the context function I get an error stating TypeError: functionName is not a function. Here is an image of the error that comes up:
[Not a Function Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7I2n.png)

I haven't been able to figure out why this is an issue and could really use a hand figuring this out as I would much rather have the ability to automatically re-render my components when data changes rather than needing to call a function to manually force a re-render for all of my components. Below are some of my code snippets to try and help illustrate the problem better.

```
//**************************
//GlobalState.js
//**************************

import React, {createContext, useReducer} from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';

const initialState = {
    loggedIn                : false,
    userState               : "undefined",
    selectedTab             : "yourProfile"
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    function logInContext(response){
        console.log("logInContextCalled")
        dispatch({
            type    : 'LOG_IN',
            payload : (response)
        });
    }

    function getUPContext(response){
        console.log("getUPContext called")
        dispatch({
            type    : 'GET_UP',
            payload : (response)
        })
    }

    function tabContext(response){
        dispatch({
            type    : 'SET_TAB',
            payload : (response)
        })
    }

    return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider value = {{loggedIn : state.loggedIn, logInContext, userState : state.userState, getUPContext, selectedTab : state.selectedTab, tabContext}}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}

//**************************
//AppReducer.js
//**************************

import React from 'react';

export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOG_IN':{
            localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", action.payload)
            return {...state, loggedIn: action.payload};
        }
        case 'GET_UP' :{
            localStorage.setItem("userState", JSON.stringify(action.payload))
            return {...state, userState: action.payload};
        }
        case 'SET_TAB' :{
            localStorage.setItem("selectedTab", action.payload)
            return{...state, selectedTab: action.payload}
        }
    }
}

//**************************
//your-profile.js
//**************************

import styles from "../styles/yourProfile.module.css"
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import qrCode from '../public/frame.png'
import { GlobalContext } from "../pages/context/GlobalState.js"
import AppReducer from '../pages/context/AppReducer'
import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'

//let loggedIn;
//let userState;

export default function YourProfile(){

    const {logInContext, getUPContext, loggedIn, userState, selectedTab, tabContext} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    //let update = forceUpdate();

//THESE FUNCTIONS THROW THE NOT A FUNCTION ERROR WHEN CALLED. ONLY OCCURS WHEN SELECTING THE TAB TO RENDER. NOT CURRENTLY HAPPENING ON REFRESH.
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use effect called")
        logInContext(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn"))
        getUPContext(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userState")))
        //update()
    }, [])


    if(loggedIn)console.log("USER IS LOGGED IN")

    console.log("Value of logged in and userState inside your-Profile")
    console.log(loggedIn)
    console.log(userState)

    if(loggedIn && userState){
    return(
        //render something
    )
    }
    else{
        return(
            //Render something elsse
        )
    }
}

//**************************
//_app.js
//**************************

import '../styles/globals.css'
import {GlobalProvider} from './context/GlobalState'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Are the components that require context, wrapped by the `GlobalProvider` component at a certain level?

Comment: Yes I should've added that in my code but the _app.js file is wrapped inside the global provider component. I added that to the code snippets now.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see the error *with the stacktrace* from the browser console.  Could you please include it in the post?

Comment: all we can say from this code snippet is that whatever the context is at the moment of the crash - presumably provided by a `GlobalContext.provider`, but if not then it could be the default value of that context - does not have a `logInContext` property, or if it does its value is not a function. But without seeing what value you're providing it's impossible to say any more. You have plenty of starting points for debugging here (either with React devtools, stepping through the code or even just `console.log`-ing at points), but we can't do that for you without your full code.

Comment: @Doc I added an image to the post.

Comment: Just a tip - I'm not sure this is causing a problem in this particular case - but your functions get redefined on every render now. I'd be a bit careful when using context, as you may run into unforeseen problems if the values provided by context are not stable.

These functions do not rely on state, so you could define them outside of the component, and then you'd always pass the same functions into context.

Comment: @GøranCantona Do you mind explaining how they are being redefined?

Comment: Any function defined inside a component, will be redefined every time that component renders. They get a new reference, so it's basically not the same function anymore, if you compare them. It may not be a problem if this is the root component, and it only render once. But if you're not sure, it's nice to know that your functions are not triggering updates just because they're not stable. I personally only define functions like this if they're being used only for event handlers inside the current component. I never pass unstable functions to other components.

Comment: @GøranCantona Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but are you saying that the functions defined inside the GlobalState.js file are being redefined everytime that the GlobalProvider component is rendering? If so should do you have any suggestions on how to resolve that?

Comment: I'll submit an answer, and then we can discuss there, ok? I think I may have spotted another problem, but I didn't run this code myself, so I'm not sure.

Comment: My bad, I somehow overlooked that the functions need access to dispatch, so just moving them outside the component won't work. I'll provide a couple of alternatives though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the functions passed into context in useCallback - this will ensure they are only defined once, due to the empty dependency array. This is safe, since the only dependency is dispatch, which is guaranteed to be stable. I also destructured state, so that you can refer to the state variables by their names.

I also removed the parenthesis around the response inside the functions. I think that may help, but I don't have the complete code to test it.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useCallback } from 'react'
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  userState: 'undefined',
  selectedTab: 'yourProfile',
}
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState)

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [{ loggedIn, userState, selectedTab }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    AppReducer,
    initialState
  )

  const logInContext = useCallback((response) => {
    console.log('logInContextCalled')
    dispatch({
      type: 'LOG_IN',
      payload: response,
    })
  }, [])

  const getUPContext = useCallback((response) => {
    console.log('getUpContext called')
    dispatch({
      type: 'GET_UP',
      payload: response,
    })
  }, [])

  const tabContext = useCallback((response) => {
    console.log('setTabContext called')
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_TAB',
      payload: response,
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        loggedIn,
        logInContext,
        userState,
        getUPContext,
        selectedTab,
        tabContext,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I understand this is your first web app, so I'll try to explain a few basic things when it comes to React. There are many "bad" tutorials out there, teaching bad habits.

One such bad habit is to utilise useEffect to write imperative React code - micro managing when effects trigger. Try to avoid that. I know it can be hard sometimes. When you access data from props, state or context inside useEffect (including functions), add it to the dependency array. This will ensure the effect is triggered whenever the data changes. This is why supplying unstable functions to components (and context) should be avoided.

If you supply an empty dependency array to useEffect, it will run only once - when the component mounts. That is, unless you're on React 18 and in strict mode. Then it will trigger twice. Use useEffect with care.

I would also advice you to name your functions differently. Different names won't change the behaviour, but reasoning with the code is easier when functions have reasonable names. Some alternative function names could be `logIn`, `getProfile` and `setTab`. Adding context to their names is just confusing.

Having said that, one advantage of using useReducer over useState, is that the dispatch function is stable, and can be passed down to other components. This allows you to define the action passed in to dispatch elsewhere. You could, for example, simply add dispatch to your context, and define your functions closer to where they are being triggered. Maybe this would lead to code that is easier to debug.

I also see that you access localStorage both in the reducer and inside the dispatch functions. Reducer functions should as a general rule be pure, they should not cause side effects, such as writing to localStorage. I have a sneaking suspicion that writing and reading to/from localStorage is causing problems for you here. The error you get happens when you supply `localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')` to `logInContext`. Try splitting that piece of logic into separate parts, and see what happens.

```
const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')
console.log({storedValue, logInContext})
logInContext(storedValue)
```

This will log both the value and the function, so you can see what they are at the time of the error.

I'm sorry I can't really pinpoint the problem, but I hope some of my advice can help you find it yourself.

Comment: Well I tried to utilize your implementation here but unfortunately, I still received the error stating: 'TypeError: logInContext is not a function'

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using localStorage here?

Comment: I updated the answer with quite a bit of text, I hope that some of it will make sense to you.